# Rotate faces so normals align with an axis in C#

Tags: c#, vector, 3d, rotation

I have an array of faces, each face has an array of points in 3d space. I want to fill an array of unfolded faces that contains the faces with their normals all pointing along the z axis. DirectionA is the z axis, DirectionB is the normal of the face. I work out the angle and axis then apply it. As I have points, myPoint is a point not a vector could that be a problem? My logic is not right somewhere....

Here is my current code:

```
    public void UnfoldAll()
    {
        Vector3d directionA = new Vector3d(0, 0, 1);//z axis
        int iii = 0;
        foreach (Face f in faces)
        {
            Vector3d directionB = normals[f.normal - 1]; //normal from face
            float rotationAngle = (float)Math.Acos(directionA.DotProduct(directionB));
            Vector3d rotationAxis = directionA.CrossProduct(directionB);
            //rotate all points around axis by angle
            for (int i = 0; i < f.Corners3D.Length; i++)
            {
                Vector3d myPoint;
                myPoint.X = f.Corners3D[i].X;
                myPoint.Y = f.Corners3D[i].Y;
                myPoint.Z = f.Corners3D[i].Z;
                myPoint = Vector3d.Normalize(myPoint);
                Vector3d vxp = Vector3d.CrossProduct(rotationAxis, myPoint);
                Vector3d vxvxp = Vector3d.CrossProduct(rotationAxis, vxp);
                Vector3d final = directionB;
                var angle = Math.Sin(rotationAngle);
                var angle2 = 1 - Math.Cos(rotationAngle);
                final.X += (angle * vxp.X) + (angle2 * vxvxp.X);
                final.Y += (angle * vxp.Y) + (angle2 * vxvxp.Y);
                final.Z += (angle * vxp.Z) + (angle2 * vxvxp.Z);
                unfoldedFaces[iii].Corners3D[i].X = final.X;
                unfoldedFaces[iii].Corners3D[i].Y = final.Y;
                unfoldedFaces[iii].Corners3D[i].Z = final.Z;
            }
        }
        iii++;
    }
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you that was helpful, here is my code if anyone else needs help:

```
    public void UnfoldAll()
    {
        Vector3d directionA = new Vector3d(0, 0, 1);//z axis
        unfoldedFaces = new UnfoldedFace[faces.Length];
        int iii = 0;
        foreach (Face f in faces)
        {
            unfoldedFaces[iii].Corners3D = f.Corners3D;
            Vector3d directionB = normals[f.normal - 1]; //normal from face
            directionB = Vector3d.Normalize(directionB);
            Vector3d vxp = Vector3d.CrossProduct(directionA, directionB);
            float rotationAngle = (float)Math.Acos(directionA.DotProduct(directionB));
            Quaternion q = Quaternion.FromAxisAngleQ(vxp, rotationAngle);
            q.Rotate(unfoldedFaces[iii].Corners3D);
            iii++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When doing any kind of 3D transformation, it is usually a good idea to stay away from angles if you can. Things tend to be easier if you stick to matrices, quaternions and vectors as much as possible.

If you want to rotate a face you should find a transform that describes the rotation, and then simply apply this transform to each of the vertices to get the rotated triangle. You could use either a matrix or a quaternion to describe a rotational transform.

The exact method will depend a bit on what library you are using for transforms. For Unity3D you have the [Quaternion.FromToRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html) that should do what you want, just input the current normal as the from vector, and the desired normal as the toDirection.

If you are using System.Numerics you can use [Quaternion.FromAxisAngle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.quaternion.createfromaxisangle?view=net-7.0). Just take the cross product your two normals to get the axis, and take the arc cos of the dot-product to get the angle. Don't forget to ensure the normals are normalized.

Comment: Thanks I am not using unity but will try to modify my code.